# Why audit returns null version

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, hibernate-envers

Having a pom like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>a</groupId>
    <artifactId>a</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <exec.mainClass>Test</exec.mainClass>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.10.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

And a main-class/entity like this:

```
import java.util.Calendar;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Version;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Environment;
import org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect;
import org.hibernate.envers.AuditReader;
import org.hibernate.envers.AuditReaderFactory;
import org.hibernate.envers.Audited;
import org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl;

@Entity
@Audited
public class Test {
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Configuration c = new Configuration();
        c.setProperty(Environment.DIALECT, HSQLDialect.class.getCanonicalName());
        c.setProperty(Environment.URL, "jdbc:hsqldb:mem:.");
        c.setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", "sa");
        c.setProperty(Environment.HBM2DDL_AUTO, "create-drop");
        c.addAnnotatedClass(Test.class);
        SessionFactoryImpl sf = (SessionFactoryImpl) c.buildSessionFactory();
        Session s = sf.openSession();

        Transaction insert = s.beginTransaction();
        Test e = new Test();
        e.text = "Hello World!";
        e.id = 1;
        s.save(e);
        s.flush();
        System.out.println(e.version.getTimeInMillis());
        insert.commit();

        Transaction update = s.beginTransaction();
        e.text = "Foobar";
        s.persist(e);
        s.flush();
        System.out.println(e.version.getTimeInMillis());
        update.commit();

        AuditReader r = AuditReaderFactory.get(s);
        System.out.println(r.find(Test.class, e.id, 1).version);
        System.out.println(r.find(Test.class, e.id, 2).version);

        sf.getServiceRegistry().destroy();
    }

    @Id
    Integer id;

    @Version
    Calendar version;

    @Column
    String text;
}
```

I get this output:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building a 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ a ---
[INFO] Deleting C:\Users\devel\workspace\a\target
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ a ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\devel\workspace\a\src\main\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ a ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding Cp1252, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to C:\Users\devel\workspace\a\target\classes
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ a ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\devel\workspace\a\src\test\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ a ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ a ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ a ---
[INFO] Building jar: C:\Users\devel\workspace\a\target\a-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ a ---
[INFO] Installing C:\Users\devel\workspace\a\target\a-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar to C:\Users\devel\.m2\repository\a\a\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\a-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] Installing C:\Users\devel\workspace\a\pom.xml to C:\Users\devel\.m2\repository\a\a\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\a-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO]
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:java (default-cli) @ a ---
Mai 28, 2017 11:27:06 AM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.5.Final}
Mai 28, 2017 11:27:06 AM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.10.Final}
Mai 28, 2017 11:27:06 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Mai 28, 2017 11:27:06 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
Mai 28, 2017 11:27:06 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH000402: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
Mai 28, 2017 11:27:06 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH000401: using driver [null] at URL [jdbc:hsqldb:mem:.]
Mai 28, 2017 11:27:06 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH000046: Connection properties: {user=sa}
Mai 28, 2017 11:27:06 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH000006: Autocommit mode: false
Mai 28, 2017 11:27:06 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
Mai 28, 2017 11:27:06 AM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect
Mai 28, 2017 11:27:06 AM org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator initiateService
INFO: HHH000399: Using default transaction strategy (direct JDBC transactions)
Mai 28, 2017 11:27:06 AM org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory <init>
INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
Mai 28, 2017 11:27:07 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport execute
INFO: HHH000227: Running hbm2ddl schema export
Mai 28, 2017 11:27:07 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport perform
ERROR: HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table Test_AUD drop constraint FK_p3jg7xwj0p2hij6o3otnb60uj
Mai 28, 2017 11:27:07 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport perform
ERROR: user lacks privilege or object not found: PUBLIC.TEST_AUD
Mai 28, 2017 11:27:07 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport execute
INFO: HHH000230: Schema export complete
1495963627299
1495963627315
null
null
Mai 28, 2017 11:27:07 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl stop
INFO: HHH000030: Cleaning up connection pool [jdbc:hsqldb:mem:.]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.438 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-05-28T11:27:07+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 27M/435M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Why is the version-field null in old revisions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected due to`org.hibernate.envers.do_not_audit_optimistic_locking_field`.

Envers sets this propety to `true` by default and therefore any annotated `@Version` properties on an entity won't be audited, won't be included in the audit table schema, and therefore will be null when you fetch audit entities from the envers history tables.

If you want the `@Version` annotated fields to be audited as well, please change the mentioned property to `false` in your hibernate configuration.  Doing this however does imply a schema update is necessary and your old history records will continue to report null values.

Comment: Looks like you are an authorithy in Envers. This decision (to make it default true) was not a gambling decision. Why is the risk low to loose that information?

Comment: It was most likely done this way to be backward compatible with earlier versions and the prior maintainers never decided to change that behavior, leaving that up to the implementors to decide on their own.